# How to assess L2 throughput limit

Tags: performance, networking, ethernet

The compute board has 2 100Gbps ports, one connects to a client machine, the other server machine which runs HTTP server. Client machine generates HTTP requests to the HTTP server and all traffic go through this compute board.

So given this setup, I wonder what is the upper bound of L2 throughput of the board? Let's assume the board's internal bus and processing are more than enough to handle 200Gbps throughput, and client and server machines are both powerful enough to saturate the board.

I think the upper bound is 100Gbps. But somehow I am not so sure, is it possible a 100G port can handle 100G ingress and 100G egress at the same time? If so, that means the upper board is 200Gbps, is that right?

Comment: Assuming you mean ethernet and throughput is application data, you must consider the protocol overhead. Ethernet has a seven octet preamble, one octet SFD, four octet FCS, and a 12 octet inter-packet gap, all per frame, and each frame has a 1500 octet payload limit. The payload will have IP overhead (minimum 20 octets for IPv4 or 40 octets for IPv6), and the transport protocol overhead (minimum 20 octets for TCP or eight octets for UDP). If you subtract all the overhead, then you get the maximum application data per frame.

Comment: You may need to consider the processing time for the intermediate board. Modern switches do it all in hardware using ASICs and can achieve wirespeed switching, but using software to switch frames is slower. If it is routing (different networks), the the board must strip the frames from the packets, forward the packets to the next interface, and build new frames for the packets on the next network (an inherently slower process).